# While clicking add to cart button the item should be added in cart.html with showing the image and data

Tags: javascript, html

Sir/Madam,
I have written a html code for add to cart button it is working properly as

Name

Price

Quantity

Total

VI-John Almond Oil

Rs.100.00

-

1

+

but it need to be displayed as

Name: Vi-John Almond oil

Price: Rs.100.00   ....like wise in same row name attribute and the name of the product.
I have downloaded jscart.js code from https://code.google.com/p/jscart/.
And also "While clicking add to cart it should redirect to cart.html page and there it must show the above details of the product".

How to redirect it, Please help me.

html code with javascript:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscart.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

     simpleCart.email = "email@address.com";
     simpleCart.checkoutTo = PayPal;
     simpleCart.currency = INR;
     simpleCart.taxRate  = 0.078;
     simpleCart.shippingQuantityRate = 1.00;
     simpleCart.cartHeaders = ["Thumb_image_noHeader", "Name" , "Size_input_div_div", "Price" , "decrement_noHeader" ,                  "Quantity", "increment_noHeader", "remove_noHeader", "Total" ];
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>


             <div class="choose">
            <li class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
            <table><tr>
       <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="simpleCart.add('name=VI-John Almond Oil','price=100','quantity=1');" >Add to cart</a></p></td>
                </tr></table>
            <table border="2"><tr><td ><span class="simpleCart_items"></span></td></tr></table> 
            </li>

    Cart: <span class="simpleCart_total"></span> (<span class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> items) <br />
  <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_empty">Empty Cart</a> 

     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Please improve the question by adding things you have tried and removing unnecessary distractions from it..

Comment: Sir I have edited my code pls analyze the code and help me